# RSpec / Shoulda validate_presence_of multiple attributes syntax

Tags: rspec, shoulda

When testing for `validate_presence_of` for multiple attributes using Shoulda / RSpec I get these long and repeating blocks of code likes this:

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:text) }
it { should validate_presence_of(:user) }
it { should validate_presence_of(:commentable) }
[...]
```

Is there a way to DRY this up? Something like this:

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:text, :user, :commentable,...) }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing built-in to Shoulda for this. Often you will want to chain options to the shoulda macros, e.g. `.with_message(...)`, so your syntax suggestion wouldn't be possible for those cases.

You could instead do something like:

```
[:text, :user, :commentable].each do |field|
  it { should validate_presence_of(field) }
end
```

However, I wouldn't worry too much about having a little bit of duplication in your test suite for the sake of easier reading and maintaining.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that this way:

```
  describe "Validations" do
    %i[text user strict_start commentable].each do |field|
      it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(field) }
    end
  end
```